# How to print statement with line and stack trace in Haskell?

Tags: debugging, haskell, printing, stdout

How do you make a print statement with a line number and stack trace in Haskell?

Answer (score 3):

You might like to play with [GHC.Stack](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/GHC-Stack.html) in the latest release of GHC.

Comment: Sorry, but I will totally use GHC.Stack in my library

Answer (score 0):

Either use this...

1. [Haskell Print Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCKo0.png) - http://hackage.haskell.org/package/print-debugger

Or use this...

2. [Debug.Trace.traceStack](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html) - https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html

The former can print a single line formatted. The latter can print multiple lines unformatted.

Debug.Trace.traceStack requires compiling with -frof and -fprof-auto and running with +RTS -xc

Debug.Trace.traceStack Example (from "[What I Wish I Knew When Learning Haskell](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/)"):

```
http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/):
    $ ghc -O0 -rtsopts=all -prof -auto-all --make stacktrace.hs
    ./stacktrace +RTS -xc
```

Haskell Print Debugger Example:

-- https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCKo0.png

```
import Debug.Print.StackTraceDebug

main = debugTraceIO "This has a stack trace."

____________________________________________
This has a stack trace. in thread "1" :
    at Main.call(Main.hs:5)
```

If you just need to find your print statements the first option is a better choice.

---

p.s. I am advertising my own package located here:

https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/HaskellPrintDebugger